# Removing part of character of filename MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

[image]I put the similar question here yesterday, and I got a super good answer and I thank the one who helped me with that. Unfortunately, I noticed that with this solution I could not solve my problem.

That's why I'm back today, it's about I want to run the script in the database (`MSSQL`), maybe someone could tell me how I should write it.

**The table name is `[Description]` the column `[displayname]`**
**my table has over 200000 filenames  with different file type (png, jpg, zip, pdf, ...)**

```
SELECT [displayname]
FROM [dbo]. [Description]
```

**Current file names:**

```
|                 DisplayName                    |
|------------------------------------------------|
| KM_003__Rheihe 4~DEL~389948.pdf                |
| KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3~DEL~391098.pdf     |
| KM_008__Grundriss~DEL~391042.pdf               |
| KM_006__Breite~DEL~398646.zip                  |
| KM_005_Hoch~DEL~356477.dwg                     |
| SAM_0440~DEL~3088.JPG                          |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
```

**What I want it to be:**

```
|                DisplayName                     |
|------------------------------------------------|
| KM_003__Rheihe 4.pdf                           |
| KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3.pdf                |
| KM_008__Grundriss.pdf                          |
| KM_006__Breite.zip                             |
| KM_005_Hoch.dwg                                |
| SAM_0440.JPG                                   |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
```

I updated my request if i execute this request

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN displayname LIKE '%~%' THEN rtrim(left(displayname,charindex('~',displayname)-1)) ELSE displayname END) AS displayname FROM Description
```

this splited the Filetype that mean i receive

```
|                DisplayName                     |
|------------------------------------------------|
| KM_003__Rheihe 4                               |
| KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3                    |
| KM_008__Grundriss                              |
| KM_006__Breite                                 |
| KM_005_Hoch                                    |
| SAM_0440                                       |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
|              ...                               |
```

Any help/pointers would greatly be appreciated

Comment: So you want to remove any characters after the `tilde`? Do the `.zip` and `.dwg` extensions get removed too?

Comment: @ Martin, exactly

Comment: There are several posted answers that **exactly produce the output you have requested**.  If this is not correct, can you _clarify exactly what you are looking for_.

Comment: So the logic is based on finding the first '~' character and removing everything from that postion to the extension. If that first '~' is preceded by a space (or any number of spaces?) remove it as well. Student, you won't learn much if you ask others to distill your logic into a pattern and then write the code based on that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the answer to produce the output you have now updated your question with, which includes the extension for all files types:

```
CREATE TABLE #Description (displayname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #Description VALUES ('KM_003__Rheihe 4 ~ DEL ~ 389948.pdf'),('KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3 ~ DEL ~ 391098.pdf'),('KM_008__Grundriss ~ DEL ~ 391042.pdf'),('KM_006__Breite~DEL~398646.zip'),('KM_005_Hoch~DEL~356477.dwg');

SELECT  displayname,
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('~', displayname) > 0 THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(LEFT(displayname, CHARINDEX('~', displayname) - 1)), RIGHT(displayname, 4))
            ELSE displayname
        END AS NewDisplayName
  FROM  #Description

DROP TABLE #Description
```

Outputs:

```
DisplayName                                     NewDisplayName
KM_003__Rheihe 4 ~ DEL ~ 389948.pdf             KM_003__Rheihe 4.pdf
KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3 ~ DEL ~ 391098.pdf  KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3.pdf
KM_008__Grundriss ~ DEL ~ 391042.pdf            KM_008__Grundriss.pdf
KM_006__Breite~DEL~398646.zip                   KM_006__Breite.zip
KM_005_Hoch~DEL~356477.dwg                      KM_005_Hoch.dwg
```

This will first remove any characters after the tilde symbol `~` and then append the last 4 characters of `DisplayName` to the output.

**Edit Following Extended Discussion With OP**

Use the following code against your existing table to get the results output as you requested:

```
SELECT  displayname,
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('~', displayname) > 0 THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(LEFT(displayname, CHARINDEX('~', displayname) - 1)), RIGHT(displayname, 4))
            ELSE displayname
        END AS NewDisplayName
  FROM  Description
```

Do not use `CASE WHEN displayname LIKE '%~%'` (as you mentioned in your comment).  The use of `CHARINDEX` as I have indicated is much better.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202825/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-removing-part-of-character-of-filename-mssql).

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation could be ugly in SQL Server but here is my go at it:

```
SELECT DisplayName, prefix + suffix
FROM (VALUES
    ('KM_003__Rheihe 4 ~ DEL ~ 389948.pdf'),
    ('KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3 ~ DEL ~ 391098.pdf'),
    ('KM_008__Grundriss ~ DEL ~ 391042.pdf'),
    ('KM_006__Breite~DEL~398646.zip'),
    ('KM_005_Hoch~DEL~356477.dwg'),
    ('foobar.pdf'),
    ('foobar~DEL~'),
    ('foobar')
) AS Description(DisplayName)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CHARINDEX(' ~ DEL ~ ', DisplayName)
         , CHARINDEX('~DEL~', DisplayName)
) AS ca1(pos1, pos2)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN pos1 > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('.', DisplayName, pos1 + 1)
           WHEN pos2 > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('.', DisplayName, pos2 + 1)
           ELSE 0
           END
) AS ca2(pos3)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN pos1 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(DisplayName, 1, pos1 - 1)
           WHEN pos2 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(DisplayName, 1, pos2 - 1)
           ELSE DisplayName
           END,
           CASE
           WHEN pos3 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(DisplayName, pos3, 999)
           ELSE ''
           END
) AS ca3(prefix, suffix)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Solution My problem is just the parenthesis, how will I write the parenthesis at the beginning and at the end of each filename, I have over 200000 filenames

Comment: There is no mention of parenthesis in your question. BTW, `'(' + prefix + suffix + ')'`

Comment: Sorry my frriend, you have rigth, the filename look like this 105_Wrathchild~DEL~1933.mp3
105_Wrathchild~DEL~1936.mp3
107_Blood Brothers~DEL~1937.mp3 i have more than 200000

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: You code generate a new table without tablename , buy with the new filename

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'KM_003__Rheihe 4 ~ DEL ~ 389948.pdf'

select concat(rtrim(substring(@str, 1
    , case when charindex('~ DEL ~', @str) > 0 then charindex('~ DEL ~', @str) else charindex('~DEL~', @str) end - 1)) ,  right(@str, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2897b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Description
CREATE TABLE Description (DisplayName varchar(255))
INSERT INTO Description(DisplayName)VALUES('KM_003__Rheihe 4 ~ DEL ~ 389948.pdf'),
                        ('KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3 ~ DEL ~ 391098.pdf'),
                        ('KM_008__Grundriss ~ DEL ~ 391042.pdf'),
                        ('KM_006__Breite~DEL~398646.zip'),
                        ('KM_005_Hoch~DEL~356477.dwg')
```

**Query 1**:

```
 SELECT 

 CONCAT(LEFT(DisplayName
             , CHARINDEX('~', DisplayName) - 1),RIGHT(DisplayName,4))

             FROM Description
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2897b/1/0)**:

```
|                                  |
|----------------------------------|
|            KM_003__Rheihe 4 .pdf |
| KM_004__Reite 2 und Reite 3 .pdf |
|           KM_008__Grundriss .pdf |
|               KM_006__Breite.zip |
|                  KM_005_Hoch.dwg |
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202783/discussion-on-answer-by-xxx-removing-part-of-character-of-filename-mssql).

Comment: Thank for zou help i have the solution  UPDATE Description
SET DISPLAY_NAME =
(CASE WHEN DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%~%' AND DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%.%' THEN rtrim(left(DISPLAY_NAME,charindex('~',DISPLAY_NAME)-1)) 
+ right(DISPLAY_NAME,charindex('.',reverse(DISPLAY_NAME))) ELSE DISPLAY_NAME END)